# VSTemplate with build action

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

How do you create a VSTemplate so that it automatically sets the build action as "content" not the default which is "none"?

Comment: Do you mean an item template or a project template?

Answer (score 3):

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067247/how-do-i-associate-a-custom-default-build-action-to-a-custom-file-type-in-visual), instead of specifying `SubType`, you should specify the `ItemType` attribute to 'Content'.

```
<ProjectItem ItemType="Content" ... > ... </ProjectItem>
```

I tried it and it works! (and yes, it's not very intuitive)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the SubType attribute of the ProjectItem to Content?

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't look like this can be done from the .vstemplate file, however it looks like [you can user .pkgdef file](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2010/07/02/Visual-Studio-default-build-action-for-non-default-file-types.aspx) to accomplish what you want.